# Change "Everyone" permission from "no access" to "read and write" Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, osx-yosemite

I recently bought a mac and am having issues with file permissions. When I download a file from the internet the permissions for the "everyone" user are set to "no access". This is causing issues for me when trying to add them to a website or view them in the browser. I am able to manually change this with `get info` but it's inefficient when working with lots of files. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue was with XAMPP and decided to switch to MAMP. XAMPP had some issue with one of it's configuration files that was causing issues and as soon as I switched to MAMP and moved my files, the issues were completely gone.

Answer (score 1):

Have been having the same issue. Got a new MBP, and everything that lands in downloads gets set to Everyone - No Access. Annoying to have to chmod every time. So, found this from 2010:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=912501

which also points to:
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201684

No idea why this would be the case by default, though...